# Ref an array in vuejs drop forEach undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this piece of code :

```
console.log(this.$refs[`roomRows${this.currentRoom}`]);
(this.$refs[`roomRows${this.currentRoom}`] || []).forEach((r) => {
    (window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame)(
          () => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
            r.scrollLeft = scroll.position.x;
          },
        );
      });
```

I have a error : `(this.$refs["roomRows".concat(...)] || []).forEach is not a function`, but this ref exist on the page, because I have the result in console.log;

Please see the error from browser:

[image]

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `console.log`, as can be seen, is an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), while`.forEach` method is for array-like objects. You may want to use that method on the element [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) by accessing the `childNodes` property, like this:

```
(this.$refs["roomRows".concat(...)]?.childNodes || []).forEach
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, small questions. Is possible to get like that :